# Converting Private Workspace to Public workspace

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

In TFS 2012 there is a new feature [Public workspace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/11/08/tfs2010-public-workspaces.aspx). If public workspace is created then it is accessible by all users. I want to know can I convert the private workspace to public workspace?

In my environment there are so many developers and only some developers have permission for checkin. So after developer does all the changes he creates shelveset and share with with developer who checkin the files.

Now I am planning that developers create a private workspace and after he has done all the changes he converts it to public workspace and the another developer who has checkin permission does the checkin. Reason for not creating public workspace in the beginning is that there are so many developers with lot of workspaces . So in solution explorer shows more than 100s of workspaces.It's difficult to select from the list and also there is risk that one developers changes code of another workspace by mistake. So I am planning to convert the private workspace to public when required to checkin and after checkin workspace is deleted. So is there  any method to convert the private workspace to public workspace?

Comment: It is easier to manage, and has a much, much higher amount of trace-ability if you use shelvesets for this workflow, and not workspaces.

Comment: @AndrewClear But there is no need to create shelveset, inform other developer, he again creates new workspace and finds the shelve set and unshelve it. These all steps can be avoided i think. Also if it is possible to change private workspace to public then i will try to automate it.

Comment: Why is the need to create a new workspace when unshelving? You should be able to unshelve into an existing workspace without problems. As an aside, have you considered branching and code promotion to control check-ins, rather than shelvesets and/or workspaces. Using either shelvesets or workspaces is using a piece of functionality for something other than its intended purpose; it will never work seamlessly.